# Identify the connector type from a picture

Tags: identification, connector, power-connector

I am trying to create a PCB board that connects to multiple solenoid values .
The connector looks familiar but I am having a hard time finding out what kind of PCB connector to use for mating with the ones from the picture. Any help is appreciated .

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like a common jst connector. Measure the sides and the pin to pin spacing.

Comment: It does look like JST VH-series connector, but seems to be missing two keying ridges on the sides. Better photo quality and pitch might indeed help identification.

Comment: I found it on a ebay listing and it says 2.5 mm pitch. Sadly these are the best pictures i got.

Comment: Please provide dimensions with component is questions

Comment: I wish I had more information on it. However, scouring the internet , I find the following link which seems to be probably the one in question.
https://www.ebay.com/itm/JST-XH-2-5mm-2-Pin-Connector-with-LOCK-Plug-Wire-Lengh-300mm-x-10-Sets/171351041601

Answer (score 1):

I am a maker too, the name is JST 2-Pin connector.